# Keyboard layout add/remove problems (gnome)

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout

I have 3 keyboard layouts on my laptop. One is rarely used, so i wrote a small script to add and remove it as needed. Here is the script content:

```
LAYOUT=`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`

if [ "$LAYOUT" != "[('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'ru'), ('xkb', 'ara')]" ]; then
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'ru'), ('xkb', 'ara')]"
else
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'ru')]"
fi

exit 0
```

It works, but sometimes even if Arabic layout added, and i can switch to it, when i enter something on my keyboard, it still types in English, even though the indicator shows Arabic. Restarting gnome shell with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd> doesn't help and even logout/login doesn't help either. Reboot helps, and everything starts to work as it supposed to be. How can i debug the issue and fix it? Also, if i'm doing add/remove keyboard layout by hotkey somehow wrong, and there is a better way, advice will be appreciated.